# How to export dataset to xls and save on server harddisk

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, download

I used the following code to convert a dataset into xls. It works fine but it throws an error.  (Some formatting problem)

**I want to save an xls file created in a specific location without the user's permission.**

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter getData = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM profile", conn);
data.Clear();
getData.Fill(data);
conn.Close();
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.Charset = "";
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" +"siv" +"\"");
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
    DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
    dg.DataBind();
    dg.RenderControl(htw);
    response.Write(sw.ToString());
    response.End();
}
```

Comment: What are you asking in the question? You mention something about a formatting error (Maybe that is null columns zero idea). Then you want to save it with out user permission - Is that saving it on the server or on the client machine? If it is the client machine and it looks like a web browser well that is up to the browser and the users settings on that machine.

Comment: @Mike it say it was ub different format than extension

Answer (score 6):

That is obviously not possible because that would pose an enormous **security risk**. You can't drop files onto the users hard drive.

There is no workaround that doesn't require the users consent. If there was I'd be very nervous to use a web browser...

If you manage to do this you probably are rewarded 50,000$ in cash by Google as part of their security reward program.

Comment: FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath+"a.xml", 
FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
ds.WriteXml(fs);
fs.Close();
i Used this to save an xml file like that

Comment: @Sivashankar, that writes the file to the server's hard disk. You can't access the disk of the user.

Comment: ok the tell me how can i do that. i mean writing on server harddisk

Comment: @Sivashankar not sure what you mean. You just posted a code snippet that does just that (write to the server hard disk). You already know how that works.

Comment: no when i run that code it prompt me to give the location to save xls